# Круг с тремя разными цветами границ

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

У меня есть `CSS` для круга с одним цветом границы:

```css
.circle {
  border: 6px solid #ffd511;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">17</div>
```

Как я должен изменить `CSS`, чтобы иметь три цвета границы - как на часах:

- От 0 до 4 цвет #1
- От 4 до 8 цвет #2
- От 8 до 12 цвет #3

Я уверен, что это возможно, с элементом `<canvas>`, но мне это не удается.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circle with three different border colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37206635/7394871) от участника  [@Legionar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631551/legionar).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206635/circle-with-three-different-border-colors/37207073#37207073

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете создать границу окружности, разделенную на 3 части с помощью [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction), используя:

- [circle element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)
- и атрибут [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)  для разделения окружности на  сектора

Ниже пример:

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="0,2.09,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="0,10.47,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="2.09,16.75,6.3" />
</svg>
```

**Edit**

Для добавления текста внутри окружности, вы можете использовать [svg text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="0,2.09,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="0,10.47,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="2.09,16.75,6.3" />
  <text x="5" y="6.5" text-anchor="middle" font-size="5">17</text>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207073/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>